# Matching an irregular grid on an image without cuttin of objects

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have an image with a bunch of objects like eg. this:

[image]

The objects may look different, but the main point is that the objects do not touch and have some seperation.

Now I need to segment this image into smaller tiles for a production process.
Basically, it is a parallelized process with multiple tools, and each tool has a position & working range, the positions are roughly on a grid, but not perfectly.

Visualized as a voronoi diagram, the positions of the tools and their respective "working cells" look somewhat like this:

[image]

However, and this will be important later on, each tool can reach somewhat further into the neighbouring cells if necessary.

Overlayed, it looks like this:

[image]

Now to the objective:

I need to get a binary mask for the working area of each tool. So just taking the voronoi cells, a mask for one such cell might look like this:

[image]

But here comes the challenge:
If possible, the objects should not cross cell borders. Of course, this is not possible everywhere. But if just a small edge of an object penetrates into the next cell like this (less than 25% into the neighbouring cell)

[image]

then the mask should be adjusted so it all gets processed by one tool, so the mask for the working area of the lower tool should look like this:

[image]

(And of course, the mask for the upper tool should have a corresponding cutout, so the area does not get processed twice)

Now, I am sure there is no "one-line" solution. But since I am not that deep into image processing algorithms, I wanted to check if there is some method (preferably in OpenCV) that might make my life somewhat easier instead of re-inventing the wheel. Maybe some fancy variation of flood-fill with borders or something like this.

My current best idea would be to start of with the masks from the voronoi diagram and iterate over each pixel along the boarder to check if it is cutting an object, and if it does, to trace the outline of the object pixel by pixel. But this seems pretty inefficient.

Comment: What are the restraints on those 'tiles '? Orthogonality? And what on those objects? Can there be an object small enough to fit into a tile of another object? - Before hunting for ideas better get all restraints fixed!

Comment: You'd better draw the true diagram showing the exact working area of each tool, and overlay it on the shapes.

Comment: @TaW Restraint on the tiles is the working range of the tools. They are positioned so that the working-range extends about 25% into the neighbouring tile if needed. And of course productivity should be as high as possible, so the overlap should be as small as possible, because it impeads the parallelization.

On the objects: can be anything, user supplies the bitmap-image. This ist just an example. Could also be a lot of small points, could be bigger.

Comment: Hm, if the objects 'can be anything, also be a lot of small points' I guess you would have to start with identifying them all. Indeed scanning line by line and a floodfill comes to mind to mark the ones already found. - As for the tiles, I don't quite understand: Are their shapes restrained to lines, at 90° angles? Rectangles? What kind of tile will the machines understand? - Also: Can you show a solution for your example?